# Put the numbers $1,2,...,\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ on the edges of $K_n$ satisfying any given path or cycle of length $3$ is $a,b,c$ then $(a,c)|b$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is it possible to put the numbers $1,2,...,\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ on the edges of $K_n$ satisfying any given path or cycle of length $3$ is $a,b,c$ then $(a,c)|b$ ?

We see that if one has $3$ vertices $u,v,w$ such that the edge $uv$ is even and the edge $vw$ is odd, then every edge containing the vertex $w$ is odd. I've been approaching this direction but haven't gotten anywhere yet, looking forward to hearing everyone's suggestions. Thanks very much !!

Comment: Is it only one of the possible assignments of $a, b, c$ that have to satisfy $(a, c)\mid b$, or all six? For instance, is $1, 2, 4$ a legal triangle because $(1, 2)\mid 4$, or illegal because $(2, 4)\nmid 1$?

Comment: @Arthur    $1 2 4$ is invalid because $2$ is not divisible by $(4,1)$ If $1 2 4$ is not a triangle then the path here can be $1 2 4$ or $4 2 1$ . If $1 2 4$ is $3$ sides of a triangle, then there are $6$ paths from $1 2 4$ in all.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible for $n \ge 4$.

Pick any integer $k$ such that $2k \le \binom n2 < 3k$. Then no matter which edges get the labels $k$ and $2k$, there will be a path or cycle on which the labels are $(k, x, 2k)$ for some $x$.

However, there is no possible $x$ which is divisible by the GCD of $k$ and $2k$, because $k$ and $2k$ are the only labels divisible by $k$, so this path will not satisfy the condition we want.

Comment: it is used that $k\ge2$, in fact $\binom n2 < 3k$ and $n\ge4$ implies that $k\ge3$. (OTOH, if $n=3$ then there is no integer $k$ such that $2k \le \binom n2 < 3k$, just clarifying your proof for myself, and for the record.)

Comment: Right. One of the ways to be more careful is to specify that we choose $k = \lfloor \frac{n(n-1)}{4}\rfloor$. Then it will be true for all $n$ that $2k \le \binom n2$, but we will only have $\binom n2 < 3k$ for $n\ge 4$ (which takes some checking, but not a lot).